# Are there any words, morphemes, or particles in any Chinese / Sinitic languages or dialects which don't have a set Hanzi character?

Tags: dialects, chinese, writing-systems, morphemes

I am pretty sure that some of the spoken varieties of modern Sinitic languages include words, morphemes, and/or particles which don't have a set written form.

Now I'm aware that some words or morphemes can be written with more than one character and that arbitrary words, including borrowings from other languages can be written with characters by way of a kind of transliteration.

What I'm asking about is either morphemes that exist only in spoken varieties of any language or dialect of Chinese and either have no written form, or can only be written in ad-hoc ways using transliterations or other kinds of character substitution.

I'm mostly interested in words/morphemes native to the variety in which they're used but borrowings may also be of some interest.

Comment: See also: [Looking for very common dialect words which have no Standard Mandarin Chinese hanzi characters](http://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/8278)

Comment: If a **script** offered no possibility to write a certain word it would not be a script (eg. Bliss). Every script can be used to write any word of any language! When you combine it with language, you get a **writing system** which acquires certain rulesets. These **graphotactics** afford single notations for many words, but several possible ones for others. **Orthography** arbitrarily limits these to 1 “set written form”. For most written languages, this happens in a **never-ending** invisible hand process, others have accepted authorities which are **naturally limited**. So the answer is yes!

Comment: Related, on Quora: http://qr.ae/7ICWWc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly. [Here is one of many LanguageLog posts on the topic](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=8922), showing two signs which use respectively the Japanese kana  の and the bopomofo symbol ㄟ, in both cases to represent a Taiwanese possessive particle [e].

Comment: But that's incorrect. The correct Chinese character exists and it is 的. Writing that as の or ㄟ would have been deliberate choices to distinguish themselves from Mandarin. Neither represent a case of Taiwanese words lacking Chinese characters.

Comment: Semaphore: that is one possible interpretation of the facts. See the comments to the LanguageLog posting for discussion about whether it is the only possible interpretation.

Comment: My speculation on the motives of using の or ㄟ is indeed no more than a possible interpretation, if one that's considerably more likely than LanguageLog's (show the right sign to a 100 Taiwanese, and more than 99 of them will say its intended to be in Hokkien). My factual statement on the existence of a Chinese character for `ê` however, is not. Frankly I'm not sure what could possibly have given Victor Mair the idea that `ê` had no written form.

Comment: Please try not to post made up statistics to a forum intended for experts. Did you read the entire on-topic part of the thread? Victor is only one of the several people with interesting things to say on the topic. Unfortunately there is also quite a bit of noise to skip over from some bigoted Han cultural warrior )-:

Comment: の can be written as 之, esp. in place names

Comment: @hippietrail I skimmed it; it seemed mostly concerned with how to pronounce の and not the veracity of Victor's bizarre assumption that `ê` had no written form. I apologise if you thought I was giving "made up statistics", I merely meant to making a point about the (extremely well established) Taiwanese use of ㄟ as a signal for code-switching to Hokkien.

Comment: Ultimately, by this appalling logic, the use of G for chicken in some fried chicken stands (http://i.imgur.com/PcYWPkG.png) means "there is great uncertainty over how to write" chicken (and no, there is not). An English equivalent might be arguing that the use of Oz for Australia means "there is great uncertainty over how to write" that country's name. Both are confusing one's own ignorance of a living language, with "uncertainty" in said language.

Comment: Feel free to provide an actual argument of more substance than "its hidden somewhere in this pile of off topic comments". But I guess I'm reading Mair's posts improperly by not automatically believing his unsubstantiated claims.

Comment: @Semaphore: OK I've found the time to sift through the thread for you. The most interesting comments are by the posters Movenon, Vanya, and Michael Cannings. Movenon says "As far as etymology, I think most agree that the 本字 (original etymological character) for Taiwanese Minnan 'e' as possessive is 個 or 个" and "Also 其, which some like to write with the 異體字 (alternate character) 亓". Michael mentions another way he's seen it "a composite character of 入 on top of 下".

Comment: @hippietrail they all counter Mair and Colin Fine's claim that `ê` has no character, as I said. Etymologically, I doubt "most agree" 个 is the original character. Prof. Wu Shouli for instance favoured 丌, a much stronger case.《尚書‧康誥》：「王若曰：孟侯，朕其弟，小子封。」 《清‧王引之‧經傳釋詞‧卷五》：「其，猶之也。其與之同義，故其可訓為之，之亦可訓為其。」Note 丌/亓 is 其's old form and thus traceable to the ancient possessive 之. No doubt 个 is historically popular, though. BTW, that 入/下 Michael saw was a newly created character Yang Qingchu published in c.1992.

Comment: I'm not sure if Mair and Fine said "has no character". I know my question is about "no set or standard character". Only the latter claim makes any sense and I've tried to be clear that's what I've been looking for.

Comment: @hippietrail that claim is *literally* in the title of the  Mair post Colin Fine linked: "No character for the most frequent morpheme in Taiwanese". I mostly took issue with its complete neglect of the tradition of using 个 and (to a lesser extent) 的 - broken etymology notwithstanding. In any case, the Ministry of Education has adopted 的 as standard.

Comment: @Semaphore: 个 and  的 are discussed a lot in the rest of the thread.

Comment: @hippietrail Were you trying to make a point with that? No one besides Movenon even mentioned 个

Comment: Well I'm glad you've now read the thread. I've been looking for controversies or criticisms of Mair and haven't found anything hinting that he might be prone to bizarre assumptions and appalling logic. For now I have no basis upon which to take Semaphore's views in preference to Mair's.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is safe to say that if the language remain alive long enough, it'd be a matter of time until a character is fitted to a spoken word. Even if it didn't originally start with one (i.e., European or certain Japanese loanwords in Taiwanese), or if the original had been lost. This seems to be typically achieved by:

1. Choosing a character with a similar sound or meaning in Standard Mandarin.
2. Choosing a character that has the same pronunciation in the dialect/language.
3. Make up a new character.

Which, given the lack of a unified authority for most such languages, means there's probably a ton of dialectal words that have been written in different ways. And that's compounded by the enormity of the existing range of Chinese characters. On the other hand, that's less that a word couldn't be written properly, and much more the result of an intense marginalisation of these dialects and languages in the past century.

(The below is taken from my answer to [the thread in the Chinese Stack Exchange](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/8278))

There's a few Taiwanese words where the proper Chinese character was unknown or disputed or perhaps non-existent. This, combined with long term marginalisation of Taiwanese as a respectable medium of communication, resulted in a bit of chaos. On the other hand, in 2009 the government made an effort to standardise the writing system, so there's now a designated official characters for the more common words at least.

Anyway, here are some words that apparently had no universally agreed upon correct character (prior to 2009, at least):

- `bē/buē`: officially 袂, was/is written as , 未, indicating a negative
- `gâu`: officially , was/is written as 賢, 爻, meaning "skilled at"
- `buaih`: officially 勿愛 squished together, was/is written as 無愛, 覅, meaning "dislike"
- `suí`: officially 媠, was/is written as 美, 水, meaning "beautiful"
- `tsia̍h`: officially 食, was/is written as 噍, 吃, meaning "to eat"
- `phah`: officially 拍, was/is written as 打, 扑, meaning "to pat, slap"
- `beh/bueh`: officially 欲, was/is written as 要, 卜, meaning "to want"
- `kah`: officially 佮, was/is written as 及, 甲, 合, meaning "together, with"
- `m̄`: officially 毋, was/is written as 不, 呣, 唔, indicating a negative
- `tshù`: officially 厝, was/is written as 茨、戍, meaning "house".

Answer (score 0):

I was browsing a language-learning book in the local public library today and came across this note on page ten of [*Get Started in Cantonese* published by *Teach Yourself*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Get-Started-Cantonese-Yourself-Enhanced-ebook/dp/B00FEDJ6AS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1413885345&sr=8-1&keywords=9781444174991):

> **LANGUAGE TIP**
>   Not all the written forms of Cantonese have been standardized. For example, **aa** could be written as 呀,吖,or丫;**lāa** could be written as 啦,罅, or 喇.